# What am i missing in this Recursive Feature Elimination? Got an error for whatever i try

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Can't seem to find a workaround on this one, tried 5 different approaches but still get the same error.

Encountering an error while trying to execute the '`rfe`' function in the `caret` package.

Here's my code:

First approach:

In my first approach, i'm trying to use the '`rfe`' function directly with the required arguments. But, still receiving the same error message.

```
> nfraud_rfe <- rfe(nfraud_features, nfraud_target, sizes = c(1:ncol(nfraud_features)), method = "glm", metric = "Accuracy")

Error in rfe.default(nfraud_features, nfraud_target, sizes = c(1:ncol(nfraud_features)),  : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Second approach:

Checking the dimensions and properties, which can help. However, it seems like the issue still persists.

```
dim(nfraud_features)
dim(nfraud_target)
class(nfraud_target)
length(nfraud_target)

nfraud_rfe <- rfe(nfraud_features, nfraud_target, sizes = c(1:ncol(nfraud_features)), method = "glm", metric = "Accuracy")

> dim(nfraud_features)
[1] 15419    32
> dim(nfraud_target)
NULL
> class(nfraud_target)
[1] "numeric"
> length(nfraud_target)
[1] 15419
```

Third approach:

In the third approach, used the '`x`' and '`y`' arguments to pass the dataset and target variable. However, the same error message is still being displayed.

```
nfraud_rfe <- rfe(x = nfraud_features, y = nfraud_target, sizes = 1:ncol(nfraud_features), method = "glm", metric = "Accuracy")

Error in rfe.default(x = nfraud_features, y = nfraud_target, sizes = 1:ncol(nfraud_features),  : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Fourth approach:

In the fourth approach, i created a control object to pass additional arguments to the '`rfe`' function. But still no luck :(

```
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, 
                   method = "cv", 
                   number = 10, 
                   verbose = FALSE)

nfraud_rfe <- rfe(x = nfraud_features, 
                  y = nfraud_target, 
                  sizes = 1:ncol(nfraud_features), 
                  method = "glm", 
                  metric = "Accuracy",
                  control = ctrl)

Error in rfe.default(x = nfraud_features, y = nfraud_target, sizes = 1:ncol(nfraud_features),  : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Fifth approach:

```
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, 
                   method = "cv", 
                   number = 10, 
                   verbose = FALSE)


customMetric <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  accuracy <- sum(data$pred == data$obs) / nrow(data)
  return(accuracy)
}


caretFuncs$summary <- customMetric


nfraud_rfe <- rfe(x = nfraud_features, 
                  y = nfraud_target, 
                  sizes = 1:ncol(nfraud_features), 
                  method = "glm", 
                  metric = "customMetric",
                  control = ctrl)

Error in rfe.default(x = nfraud_features, y = nfraud_target, sizes = 1:ncol(nfraud_features),  : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

I don't know what am i missing.